# What is the correct way to have an editable "Name"-text area in Flutter App?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm quite a newbie with Flutter and coding in general:
My problem is:

I'd like to have a name of device in a Row, which should be able to be changed/rewritten after a **long press**.

The Long Press - functionality is preferrable. I Thought about just having a Container with **TextField**, but I don't know **how to implement long press** to it.

Another way I was thinking was a **TextButton**, but how to be able to rewrite the text/name in it..?

So, does anybody have experience and advice in this?

Comment: Usually it helps to share some snippets of what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 1):

wrap your textField with InkWell, like this

```
 InkWell(
              onLongPress: (){
                //do something
              },
              child: TextField(
                
              ),
            ),
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I will see where I end with InkWell.